# System.IO.IOException file already exists

Tags: c#, exception

I'm using the code below for my application to copy to appdata roaming folder.
The problem I'm having is that if application is run once it works well but if i re-run it it gives me this error :

> System.IO.IOException: 'The file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\app.exe' already exists.'

Can I somehow fix this exception because once this happen my application stop working ?

```
        string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
        string copyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        copyPath += "\\\\" + Path.GetFileName(exePath);
        File.Copy(exePath, copyPath);
```

Comment: `copyPath += "\\\\" + Path.GetFileName(exePath);` don't setup paths this way, use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) method to do this. Also why not check to see if the file exist first before trying the copy and or use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_).

Comment: You should first check if file exist or not. If file exists then you should delete it before copying.

Answer (score 2):

You just to need to specify that overwriting is allowed:

```
File.Copy(exePath, copyPath, true);
```